# Dist::Zilla: Getting install instructions into Readme.mkdn

Tags: perl, dist-zilla

I'm using Dist::Zilla to generate a README.mkdn file. I want to inject installation instructions into it using [Pod::Weaver::Section::Installation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Pod::Weaver::Section::Installation). Not sure if this can be done. There's probably a better way to do this.

Here is my weaver.ini file in my Dist::Zilla profile:

```
[@CorePrep]

[Name]
[Version]

[Generic / SYNOPSIS]
[Generic / DESCRIPTION]

[Collect / ATTRIBUTES]
command = attr

[Collect / METHODS]
command = method

[Generic / CONFIGURATION AND ENVIRONMENT]
[Generic / DEPENDENCIES]
[Generic / INCOMPATIBILITIES]
[Generic / BUGS AND LIMITATIONS]

[Installation]
[Authors]
[Legal]

[-Transformer]
transformer = List
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I thought it would use weaver.ini from my profile. Apparently, that isn't the case. I had to put the file in the root of the repo directory.